# Start menu management in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-management

1) I still have folders for programs I have uninstalled, and inside are links to files that aren't there ay more. How do I get rid of them?

2) How to make the menu open in the "all programs" mode so that I don't have to click the all programs button?

Answer (score 0):

In the All programs list, Right click on the items you don't want and select delete.

Then search your hard drive for those folder names and delete the folders if you wish.

.

[image]

Comment: No menu appears when I right-click, I can only drag the folders to reorder them (by right-clicking and holding).

Comment: No menu appears when you right-click? That's not normal at all.  Do you have anything running that might be supressing that?  Are you maybe on a domain?

Comment: Do you get a context menu anywhere else in windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the Start Menu items that you want to delete in `C:\Users\...` then look here instead:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\...`